# c++ eigenvalue and eigenvector corresponding to the smallest eigenvalue

Tags: c++, eigen

I am trying to find out the eigenvalues and the eigenvector corresponding to the smallest eigenvalue. I have a matrix `A` (nx2) and I have computed `B =  transpose(A) * a`. When I am using c++ eigen function `compute()` and print the eigenvalues of matrix `B`, it shows something like this:

```
(4.4, 0)
(72.1, 0)
```

Printing the eigenvectors it gives output:

```
(-0.97, 0)   (0.209, 0)
(-0.209, 0)  (-0.97, 0)
```

I am confused. Eigenvectors can't be zero I guess. So, for the smallest eigenvalue 4.4, is the corresponding eigenvector `(-0.97, -0.209)`?

P.S. - when I print

```
mysolution.eigenvalues()[0]
```

it prints `(4.4, 0)`. And when I print

```
mysolution.eigenvectors().col(0)
```

it prints `(-0.97, 0)   (0.209, 0)`. That's why I guess I can assume that for eigenvalue 4.4, the corresponding eigenvector is `(-0.97, -0.209)`.

Answer (score 0):

I guess you are correct.

None of your eigenvalues is null, though.  It seems that you are working with complex numbers.

Could it be that you selected a complex floating point matrix to do your computations?  Something along the lines of `MatrixX2cf` or `MatrixX2cd`.

Answer (score 0):

Every square matrix has a set of eigenvalues. But even if the matrix itself only consists of real numbers, the eigenvalues and -vectors might contain complex numbers (take (0 1;-1 0) for example)

If Eigen knows nothing about your matrix structure (i.e. is it symmetric/self-adjoint? Is it orthonormal/unitary?) but still wants to provide you with exact eigenvalues, the only general type that can hold all possible eigenvalues is a complex number.

Thus, Eigen always returns complex numbers which are represented as pairs (a, b) for a + bi. Eigen will only return real numbers if the matrix is self-adjoint, i.e. [SelfAdjointView](https://eigen.tuxfamily.org/dox/classEigen_1_1SelfAdjointView.html) is used to access the matrix.

**If you know for a fact that your matrix only has real eigenvalues, you can just extract the real part by `eigenvalue.real` since Eigen returns [std::complex](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/numeric/complex) values.**

EDIT: I just realized that if your matrix A has no complex entries, B=transposed(A)*A is self-adjoint and thus you could just use a SelfAdjointView of the matrix to compute the real eigenvalues and -vectors.